# using opencv type in header file achieve to undefined identifier

Tags: c++, opencv

The following code builds and runs with no problem (just resize an image with or without cuda)

```cpp
//#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
//#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
//#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/utils/logger.hpp>
#include <iostream>
//#include "openCVTest.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void mainTransform(InputArray src, OutputArray dest, double m) {
    resize(src, dest, Size(0, 0), m, m, INTER_CUBIC);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    utils::logging::setLogLevel(utils::logging::LOG_LEVEL_WARNING);

    const string keys =
        "{help h usage ?| |[image] [-cd=cudaIndex]}"
        "{@image        | |image to display * 1.5}"
        "{cdi           |0|cuda device index, -1 for cpu}";

    CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, keys);

    if (parser.has("help")) {
        parser.printMessage();
        return 0;
    }

    int cudaDeviceIndex = parser.get<int>("cdi");
    string imageName = parser.get<string>("@image");

    if (!parser.check()) {
        parser.printErrors();
        return 0;
    }

    const char* WIN_NAME = "Display window";

    cuda::DeviceInfo cudaDeviceInfo;
    int cedc = cuda::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount();
    if (cedc == 0 || cudaDeviceIndex >= cedc || cudaDeviceIndex < 0) {
        cout << "no cuda device " << cudaDeviceIndex << " max is " << cedc - 1 << endl;
        cudaDeviceIndex = -1;
    }
    else {
        cuda::setDevice(cudaDeviceIndex);
        cudaDeviceInfo = cuda::DeviceInfo(cudaDeviceIndex);
        cout << cedc << " cuda device(s), using index 0: " << cudaDeviceInfo.name() << endl;
    }   

    if (imageName == "") {
        return 0;
    }

    namedWindow(WIN_NAME, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    Mat image, dest;
    image = imread(imageName, IMREAD_COLOR); 
    if (image.empty()) {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    double m = 1.5;
    if (cudaDeviceIndex >= 0) {
        cout << "from gpu" << std::endl;
        cuda::GpuMat gpuImage, gpuDest;
        gpuImage.upload(image);
        cuda::resize(gpuImage, gpuDest, Size(0, 0), m, m, INTER_CUBIC);
        gpuDest.download(dest);
    }
    else {
        cout << "from cpu" << std::endl;
        mainTransform(image, dest, m);
        resize(image, dest, Size(0, 0), m, m, INTER_CUBIC);
    }

    imshow(WIN_NAME, dest); 

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;       
}
```

now, if I change to:

```
//#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
//#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
//#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/utils/logger.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "openCVTest.hpp"
```

with openCVTest.hpp:

```
#ifndef _openCVTest_h
#define _openCVTest_h

#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

void mainTransform(InputArray src, OutputArray dest, double m);

#endif
```

I got a C2065 error : undefinde identifier in line 6 of openCVTest.hpp.

I disabled precompiled header.

My goal is to move `mainTransform` definition under `main`.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is, in the hpp file:

```
void mainTransform(cv::InputArray src, cv::OutputArray dest, double m);
```

that is to use `cv::` prefix because the `using namespace` is not effective in the hpp.